# Python unbound local error on one machine but not on another

Tags: python, python-2.7

I get "UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assign" in python script on one machine but not on another where the script runs OK. Both machines are on Windows 7 and use Python 2.7.3. Any suggestions what could be the reason for this behaviour? Thank you.
Here's the code that causes the error:

```
    with open(self.temp_dir + test + ".log",'r') as log:
      for line in log:
        if "INPUT_SENTENCE" in line:
          match = patternInput.match(line)
          inputSentence = match.group(1).lower()
          if inputSentence in self.testToDiagDict[test]:
            continue
          self.testToDiagDict[test][inputSentence] = []
        if "STATS" in line:
          if "Input Sentences" in line:
            inputSentences = patternValue.findall(line)
            self.testToDiagDict[test][inputSentence].append(inputSentences[0])
```

And the trace:

```
    File "C:\X\Y\X\script.py", line 90, in extract_data
    if "Input Sentences" in line:
 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'inputSentence' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: `UnboundLocalError` is a *runtime* exception, not a syntax error. We'll need to see your code to be able to help with that.

Comment: Please provide more details - some code would be nice and the traceback.

Comment: check what s refers to on machine that it works on.   besides error does the script do what is supposed to?

Comment: I have a feeling `s` is created and assigned to within a conditional block (like an if statement), which gets executed in the first and not the second of the two machines.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
self.testToDiagDict[test][inputSentence].append(inputSentences[0])
```

There is no `inputSentence` in that scope

So the code might have worked on one machine because this `if statement`

```
if "INPUT_SENTENCE" in line:
```

evaluated to true, but in the case that it doesn't, that is when you get that error. I can't suggest a fix because I don't know what the rest of your code looks like or what you are trying to accomplish, but the much I have pointed out should allow you to reevaluate your design

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps as @inspectorG4dget says - you have a different codepath somewhere. Here is a simple example that *could* cause your error

```
def f():
    if machine1:
        s = 1
    else
        S = 2
    print s
```

If you would show the code, it would probably take just a few seconds to find